# how to make scrollable horizontally and vertically the contents of a TextView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I want to scroll the results that view in a TextView, this my xml:

```
<scroll>
<TextView
android:id="@+id/ris"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="229dp"
android:layout_weight="0.96"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
</scroll>
```

but the app crashes.

Comment: what have you tried to do to resolve the crash?  what does the crashing message say?

Answer (score 1):

add this in XML file for TextView

```
 android:scrollHorizontally="true"
 android:scrollVertically="true"
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the following as attributes in your `TextView`:

```
android:maxLines = "1"
android:scrollbars = "vertical"
```

Then once you have instantiated your `TextView`, add the line:

```
mTextView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<ScrollView> your View "</ScrollView">
```

And there must be only one child ScrollView.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="19dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/hello_world"
            tools:context=".Tester" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: By enclosing your TextView inside a ScrollView, you will gain the ScrollView behavior such as scrolling vertically.