# Textview horizontal and vertical scrolling

Tags: android, layout, scroll, textview

I want to have a horizontal and vertical scrolling textfield. On the bottom of the screen is a button. It works so far but the textview height is only as the content is. Is there a way to spawn the height to the parent element (scrollbar)?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/startStressTestBtn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:text="START StressTest"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />


    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/main_tv_scroller"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/startStressTestBtn"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_home"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scrollbars="horizontal"
                android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
        </HorizontalScrollView>
    </ScrollView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Target is that the scrollbar is at the bottom top of the button (match_parent). So I can use the "whole" screen for scrolling.

[image]

Comment: What do you have now and what do you want to have? Attach image please

Comment: Please describe better your problem?

Comment: At the moment the textview only has the height of the content like "wrap_content" constraint. You see that the horizontal scrollbar is directly under the text. I want that the height of the textview fills the empty space on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Don't put scrolls into each other, set constraints one by one, try this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/main_tv_scroller"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/startStressTestBtn"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
    </ScrollView>

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/startStressTestBtn"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
    </HorizontalScrollView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_home"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/startStressTestBtn"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/startStressTestBtn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:text="START StressTest"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Hi, here the TextView is not scrolling anymore - thats the reason why I nested the TextView in the ScrollViews (horizontal, vertical).

Comment: Do you want it to scroll vertically or horizontally? @typhon

Comment: Yes of course, thats the reason why I put the both scrollviews in this view? Also this is the first sentence of my Question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10552305/how-to-make-scrollable-horizontally-and-vertically-the-contents-of-a-textview

Comment: The scrolling is not my problem - I wan't that the HorizontalScrollView fill the space after starting the application - not after fill the scrollview with text.